# CoderByte CaesarCipher Excercise in Ruby

Tags: ruby, debugging

This is the question : Using the Ruby language, have the function CaesarCipher(str,num) take the str parameter and perform a Caesar Cipher shift on it using the num parameter as the shifting number. A Caesar Cipher works by shifting each letter in the string N places down in the alphabet (in this case N will be num). Punctuation, spaces, and capitalization should remain intact. For example if the string is "Caesar Cipher" and num is 2 the output should be "Ecguct Ekrjgt"

**Here is my code**

```
def CaesarCipher(str,num)
alphabet = ("a".."z").to_a.join("")
alphabetupcase = ("a".."z").to_a.join("").upcase
i=0
result = ""


  while i < str.length
    if alphabet.include?(str[i])
      result += alphabet[alphabet.index(str[i]) + num]
    elsif alphabetupcase.include?(str[i])
      result += alphabetupcase[alphabetupcase.index(str[i]) + num]
    else
     result += str[i]
    end
    i += 1
  end


  # code goes here
  return result 

end
```

I keep getting this error (eval):11: (eval):11:in `+': can't convert Fixnum into String (TypeError) from (eval):11:in`CaesarCipher'    from (eval):26

What is the problem with this and How can I fix this code?
Can you suggest a better solution keeping in mind I am a beginner in Ruby ?
Thank you all in advance

Comment: what string are you testing with? it works fine for me with `n = CaesarCipher("hello", 1)`. And what version of ruby are you using?

Comment: I am not using any version to be honest just doing it in CoderByte's coding space for this challenge http://coderbyte.com/CodingArea/information.php?ct=Caesar%20Cipher

I also tested it on Repl.it it worked for a few times then started giving the same error. I don't know why. Like you said it might be because of Ruby version.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work, because you miss the modulo operation - if you shift the letter 'z' by 2, you should get 'b'. And your program fails in this case. The algorithm for counting the new letter index is: `(index + shift) modulo alphabet_size`.

But I would do like this:

```
def caesar (str, num)
  str.split('').collect do |character|
    case character
    when 'a'..'z', 'A'..'Z'
      base_ascii = if character == character.upcase then 'A'.ord else 'a'.ord end
      (((character.ord - base_ascii + num) % ('a'..'z').count) + base_ascii).chr
    else
      character
    end
  end.join('')
end
```

First, iterate on every character of the string. If it is a letter, calculate the shift (note the `base_ascii`, which is the ASCII code for 'A' or 'a', depends if shift is for lower- or uppercase), which is just an index of letter (`character.ord` - base_ascii) plus the shif (`num`) modulo number of letters in the alphabet (`('a'..'z').count`). If the characters is not a letter, so space, punctation, returns it unchanged.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Grych :) I am unable to upvote it due to reputation limitations. I'll try to learn the ASCII code solution too.

Comment: on top of what @Grych said, try to follow ruby standards of snakecase method names. CamelCase causes confusion as it looks like a class name.

Comment: @MehmetRagıpAltuncu, please read my updated answer. Your code does not work properly, it only works with the example you gave, but it is just a lucky strike.

Comment: @Grych Okay I will try to understand how to use modulo operations if I can ) Thank you again

Comment: @snowe2010 Yeah CamelCase was CoderByte's format. I use snakecases for Ruby as you suggested. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I recommend taking a look at some other Caesar cypher implementations here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55049/learning-ruby-caesar-cipher